# in LXD how to access containers with their name from host

Tags: networking, lxd

In default installation of LXD, the containers can ping each other by their name like `c1` or `c1.lxd` very easy.

Containers are at a DHCP bridged network which make name resolvation trivial between them, the host also is in this network (eg : 10.0.3.1 ), but host can't do this.

Can any one help with a instruction in simple way to make it available from host?

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to put entry of container name and ip in /etc/hosts file on host this is will work

```
xx.xx.xx.xx <Container Name>
```